# React Chatbox, how to get the string displayed?

Tags: reactjs, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, react-component

I am a newbie, and am trying to build a simple restaurant recommendation web app using AWS and React. So, I am using this chat window(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chat-window). Basically, when the user types something, the chatbot gets triggered and asks questions like "what kind of food do you want?" So far, I am able to pass the user's input and get the response back from the AWS. I can log the response to the console and verify it. But I have trouble getting the response displayed in the chatbox.

Here is the snippet of the code

```
class chatBox extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            messageList: chatHistory,
            newMessagesCount: 0,
            isOpen: false
        };
    }

    // message is the user's input
    _onMessageWasSent(message) {
        var body = {
            messages: message.data['text']
        }
        // every time the user types something, this function passes the user's input to AWS
        apigClient.invokeApi(pathParams, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams, body)
            .then(function (result) { // result contains the response to the user's input
                var text = result.data.body
                console.log(text)   // logs the response to the user's input
                console.log(text.length)
            }).catch(function (result) {
            });

        this.setState({ //this displays what the user types
            messageList: [...this.state.messageList, message]
        })
    }


    // This is a function that displays the input of the other side
    // I can manually test it and see that whatever I pass to this function gets displayed as
    // the other person's speech, not the user.
    _sendMessage(text) {
        console.log("sendMessage")
        if (text.length > 0) {
            this.setState({
                messageList: [...this.state.messageList, {
                    author: 'them',
                    type: 'text',
                    data: { text }
                }],
                newMessagesCount: this.state.newMessagesCount + 1
            })
        }
    }
```

As can be seen, I am logging the response to the console. Now, I want to get the response displayed so I tried inside the constructor

```
this._onMessageWasSent = this._sendMessage.bind(this)
```

and calling the function inside _onMessageSent

```
apigClient.invokeApi(pathParams, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams, body)
            .then(function (result) { // result contains the response to the user's input
                var text = result.data.body
                console.log(text)   // logs the response to the user's input
                console.log(text.length)
                this._sendMessage(text) // Calling the function
            }).catch(function (result) {
            });

        this.setState({ //this displays what the user types
            messageList: [...this.state.messageList, message]
        })
    }
```

I can see that the _sendMessage function gets triggered, because I have a console.log. But now the chatbox displays neither the user and the chatbot. If I don't bind this._onMessageWasSent = this._sendMessage.bind(this), at least I get the user displayed.

What could be the problem??

This is my render()

```
render() {
        return (<div>
            <Launcher
                agentProfile={{
                    teamName: 'Foodophile',
                    imageUrl: 'https://a.slack-edge.com/66f9/img/avatars-teams/ava_0001-34.png'
                }}
                onMessageWasSent={this._onMessageWasSent.bind(this)}
                messageList={this.state.messageList}
                onFilesSelected={this._onFilesSelected.bind(this)}
                newMessagesCount={this.state.newMessagesCount}
                handleClick={this._handleClick.bind(this)}
                isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                showEmoji
            />
        </div>)
    }
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
class chatBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            messageList: chatHistory,
            newMessagesCount: 0,
            isOpen: false
        };
        this._onMessageWasSent = this._onMessageWasSent.bind(this);
        this._onFilesSelected = this._onFilesSelected.bind(this);
        this._handleClick = this._handleClick.bind(this);
        this._sendMessage = this._sendMessage.bind(this);
    }
    _onMessageWasSent(message) {
        var body = {
            messages: message.data['text']
        }

        apigClient.invokeApi(pathParams, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams, body)
            .then(function (result) {
                var text = result.data.body
                console.log(text)
                console.log(text.length)
                this._sendMessage(text)
            }).catch(function (result) {
            });
        this.setState({
            messageList: [...this.state.messageList, message]
        })
    }

    _sendMessage(text) {
        console.log("sendMessage")
        if (text.length > 0) {
            this.setState({
                messageList: [...this.state.messageList, {
                    author: 'them',
                    type: 'text',
                    data: { text }
                }],
                newMessagesCount: this.state.newMessagesCount + 1
            })
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (<div>
            <Launcher
                agentProfile={{
                    teamName: 'Foodophile',
                    imageUrl: 'https://a.slack-edge.com/66f9/img/avatars-teams/ava_0001-34.png'
                }}
                onMessageWasSent={this._onMessageWasSent}
                messageList={this.state.messageList}
                onFilesSelected={this._onFilesSelected}
                newMessagesCount={this.state.newMessagesCount}
                handleClick={this._handleClick}
                isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                showEmoji
            />
        </div>)
    }
```

Comment: could your share your render function?

Comment: So what does the `console.log(text)` log after binding?

Comment: Also, your first code snippet shows the same code as the one below but misses the line `this._sendMessage(text) // Calling the function` make sure you are actually not just missing that line!

Comment: @Andre Thanks for your attention. I just edited the post. You can see my render

Comment: @Michael it logs the correct response. For example, if the user typed "I want food", the response text from the chatbox is "What kind of food?", which console.log(text) logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind your class methods in class components in order to call them with `this`. But you have to do this, e.g. in the constructor BUT not in your render function!

Check out this [very nice explanation](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/) on why and how to bind your functions.

```
  constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this._onMessageWasSent = this._onMessageWasSent.bind(this);
    this._onFilesSelected = this._onFilesSelected.bind(this);
    this._handleClick = this._handleClick.bind(this);
    this._sendMessage = this._sendMessage.bind(this);
  }
```

In your render function, just pass the functions like follows:

```
render() {
        return (<div>
            <Launcher
                agentProfile={{
                    teamName: 'Foodophile',
                    imageUrl: 'https://a.slack-edge.com/66f9/img/avatars-teams/ava_0001-34.png'
                }}
                onMessageWasSent={this._onMessageWasSent}
                messageList={this.state.messageList}
                onFilesSelected={this._onFilesSelected}
                newMessagesCount={this.state.newMessagesCount}
                handleClick={this._handleClick}
                isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                showEmoji
            />
        </div>)
    }
```

Also, there is one more issue. `This` binding is a tricky thing in JavaScript and `function` vs `()=>{}` arrow functions do treat this differently. In your case, just use an arrow function instead.

```
apigClient.invokeApi(pathParams, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams, body)
            .then((result) => {
                var text = result.data.body
                console.log(text)
                console.log(text.length)
                this._sendMessage(text)
            }).catch(function (result) {
            });
```

This will make sure that `this` inside your then-callback function is still the `this` that you expect it to be. This is why, if you would refactor all your functions (`_onMessageWasSent`, `_onMessageWasSent`, `_onFilesSelected`, `handleClick`, `_sendMessage` ) to arrow functions, there is no need anymore to bind them to this in the constructor.

See this for example:

```
_onMessageWasSent = (message) =>  {
   // your function body
}
```

You could already get rid of the line `this._onMessageWasSent = this._onMessageWasSent.bind(this);`.

Read more about this binding in functions at [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp).

Comment: Thank you! I just did what you suggested. But, now when I call `this._sendMessage(text)` inside _onMessageSent, the user gets displayed but the _sendMessage function does not get triggered; the response doesn't get displayed. What else can I try?

Comment: can you update your code please :) Also, make sure to actually call `this._sendMessage(text)` you still forgot this line in your upper code example! Maybe you are not even calling that function.

Comment: I just uploaded the updated code separately. Please check and see and let me know if there is anything bad. because, it is not calling _sendMessage

Comment: I updated my code. I will double check later when I am home but you can try my code for now!

Comment: OMGG this works!! I can't thank you enough! Thanks for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: updated my answer with some links and a better example of how to use arrow functions! Good luck